# How do you output a column in Upper Case in a LINQ to SQL Query?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I would like to UCASE or ToUpper a column in my LINQ query.

```
var query = from rsn in db.RSLReasons
            orderby rsn.REFCMNT
            select new {rsn.REFCODE, rsn.REFCMNT};
dtReasons = query.ToADOTable(rec => new object[] { query });
```

If I try to run the following code:

```
var query = from rsn in db.RSLReasons
            orderby rsn.REFCMNT
            select new {rsn.REFCODE, rsn.REFCMNT.ToString()};
dtReasons = query.ToADOTable(rec => new object[] { query });
```

I get the following error message on compile:

> Invalid anonymous type member
>   declarator. Anonymous type members
>   must be declared with a member
>   assignment, simple name or member
>   access.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `ToUpper()`... but you will need to specify the property name in the anonymous type because it can no longer be inferred.

```
var query = from rsn in db.RSLReasons
            orderby rsn.REFCMNT
            select new {rsn.REFCODE, REFCMNT = rsn.REFCMNT.ToUpper()};

dtReasons = query.ToADOTable(rec => new object[] { query });
```